# How to add a new API in the framework (Framework.jar)?

Tags: android, android-source

I want to add new custom API in android framework and need to build the SDK.
But I want the new API source in /vendor folder not in /framework.

I am trying to achieve this by adding new API in framework.jar.So I can't use sdk_addon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add sdk add on there are no way to skip it if you want to have a

Comment: I tried sdk_addon but it is creating sdk for linux not windows.How to create for windows?